# Django hvad - Best practice to work with multi-lingual object in template

Tags: python, django, plugins, multilingual, django-hvad

I have an article object which has several languages. What's the best way to work with this object?

I need to display all attributes in every language.

Is is possible to get just my article object and iterate through the languages in the template?

Thanks for you help!

Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should act like this: extract each translation in single variable, put them in list ant let that list go to view. Then you can iterate through each translation in view.

Comment: hm...thats what i would have done... thought there might be a more elegant way to do it. still: thanks!